# Why is a Unicode character getting overflowed in this answer?

Tags: support, answers

Stack Overflow question https://stackoverflow.com/a/23033650 (deleted now, only visible to members with 10K+ rep) is covering all the answer options like:

-[image]

See:

[image]

It will be corrected. I put all the data inside the answer in a code block.

[image]

But why is it overflowing when the code block is not used?

Comment: The question is more as to why a code block constrains the text; most likely because it uses a scrolling block instead.

Comment: Interesting...I see http://i.stack.imgur.com/o1Aip.png. Chrome on Ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Martijn Pieters identified the difference [in his comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/229280/why-is-a-unicode-character-getting-overflowed-in-this-answer#comment752460_229280):

> The question is more as to why a code block constrains the text; most likely because it uses a scrolling block instead.

Code blocks have a maximum width and height, to prevent long lines and excessively-long code snippets from taking over the page. Content which exceeds these dimensions is hidden (with scrolling allowed to reveal it) via this rule:

```css
pre
{
 ...
 overflow: auto;
 ...
}
```

This concerns *only* the difference in how they overflow; the very different rendering is likely a browser bug.

Comment: I'd imagine the different rendering is more likely to be a difference between the fonts used, since it's sans-serif in the first case and monospace in the second. Using a blockquote might make it render the same.