# Question migrated from MSE to MSO but reputation lost

Tags: support, reputation, mso-mse-split, migration

After the split. [A Question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251173) migrated from MSE to MSO and reputation got lost from [my MSE account](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/233943/tushar-gupta) but it has not been added to [my MSO account](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/2224265/tushar-gupta).

There is no reputation tab in the profile.

What will happen to this reputation?  Will I get it back, or is it lost forever?

Comment: Oh! my internet dollars.  _Help!_

Comment: @devnull hahh Just curious to know :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no MSO account sort of thing. You can get badges specifically for MSO, but reputation is taken from your SO account.

Your StackOverflow account will be regularly updated, and that is your MSO reputation.

Now, you don't get reputation for up votes or down votes.

Now they serve for how the community takes your question or answer, and it has now got nothing to do with reputation.